# How to store data into cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to setup AWS elasticache (memcache) in my app with Nodejs.

I wanted to store json object to the cache and did

```
elastic.connect().then(function(instance){
      var profile = {
          'name':'Rohit kumar',
          'location':'Delhi',
          'emailid':'iamrohitx@gmail.com'
       }
   
      instance.set('profile', profile, false, 10000);

      instance.get('profile').then(function(cacheData){
         console.log(cacheData);
      });
});
```

The `cacheData` return `[object object]` as a string after ‘`get`’.

For some reason, I was able to set and get if the value is string but not an object

```
  instance.set('profile', 'profile 1 string', false, 10000);
  instance.get('profile').then(function(cacheData){
     console.log(cacheData); // get 'profile 1 string'
  });
```

Can `elasticache` handle json? I thought it would be weak if it can’t.

Answer (score 0):

We can store the Serializable Object only in Memcached.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.